# (AWS Opsworks) Terraform Chef provisioning: ERROR: Failed to authenticate

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, terraform, aws-opsworks

New to Terraform and I am trying to bootstrap a node to chef after the instance is created.

Here is the file:

```
resource "aws_instance" "jenkinsNode" {

provisioner "remote-exec" {
connection {
  user = "ubuntu"
  private_key = "${file("~/key/mykey.pem")}"
  host = "${aws_instance.jenkinsNode.public_ip}" 
}

inline = [
  "sudo mkdir -p /etc/chef/trusted_certs",
  "sudo curl --silent --show-error --retry 3 --location --output 
\"/etc/chef/trusted_certs/opsworks-cm-ca-2016-root.pem\" 
\"https://opsworks-cm-us-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/misc/opsworks-cm-ca-2016-root.pem\""
 ]
}

provisioner "chef" {

environment     = "_default"
run_list        = ["android-aws-nodes::updateAndroidSdk"]
node_name       = "jenkinsNodeOnDemandUpdate"
secret_key      = "${file("~/chef/mobile-chef-aws/.chef/private.pem")}"
server_url      = "https://my-opsworks-server.io/organizations/default"
recreate_client = true
user_name       = "delivery"
user_key        = "${file("~/chef/mobile-chef-aws/.chef/private.pem")}"
version         = "12.8.1"
}

connection {
user = "ubuntu"
private_key = "${file("~/key/jenkins-main.pem")}"
}

 count = 1
 instance_type = "c4.8xlarge"
 ami = "ami-0000000"
 key_name = "mykey"
 subnet_id = "subnet-00000000"
 vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-00000000"]
}
```

I am receiving the following error when I run when I try to apply the above code.  I connected and starts the bootstrap process but it keeps complaining that it can't find the private (Which I believe is created when run the "client create".  I ssh'd into the instance and I do not see the ubuntu.pem in the /etc/chef/ directory:

UPDATED
    aws_instance.jenkinsNode (chef): ERROR: Failed to authenticate to https://mobile-b9oer25dyrts1qor.us-east-1.opsworks-cm.io/organizations/default/ as delivery with key /etc/chef/delivery.pem
    aws_instance.jenkinsNode (chef): Response:  Invalid signature for user or client 'delivery'
    aws_instance.jenkinsNode (chef): Cleanup user key...

```
Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_instance.jenkinsNode: 1 error(s) occurred:

* Command "sudo knife client create jenkinsNodeOnDemandUpdate -d -f /etc/chef/client.pem -c /etc/chef/client.rb -u ubuntu --key /etc/chef/ubuntu.pem" exited with non-zero exit status: 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no key when you log in, because it is removed right after failed bootstrap

```
aws_instance.jenkinsNode (chef): Cleanup user key...
```

Double check if key (`~/key/mykey.pem`) on machine which runs Terraform is in proper format. Also it should be loaded with `$file` or put as String:

```
user_key        = "${file("~/key/mykey.pem")}"
```

Just double check if Terraform supports `~`.

Comment: I updated the code to reference the key, but now I am getting the following error: "aws_instance.jenkinsNode (chef): ERROR: Failed to authenticate to https://chef-server-cm.io/organizations/default/ as delivery with key /etc/chef/delivery.pem
aws_instance.jenkinsNode (chef): Response:  Invalid signature for user or client 'delivery'

Comment: "delivery" is the user I get when running "knife user list"

Comment: Are you using proper `delivery` user key? Can you authenticate with this key and created clients/nodes?

Comment: Ok, figured out based off your responses.  I created this chef environment using AWS Opsworks, it automatically creates the node_name, which is also the user_name also. And the key was with the kit that you have to download when the instance is created in Opsworks.